# Does the summation of $(n+1)((1+\sin(nπ/6))/3)^n$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The back of my book says it converges, but each test I've tried says the  summation diverges.
Can someone help me to know if the following converges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)\left(\frac{(1+\sin(nπ/6))}{3}\right)^n $$

Comment: Yes, please try Wolfram Alpha (very large number, but converges) - maybe try the Cauchy root test to show.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The terms are non-negative, and the $n$-th term is $\le (n+1)\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$.  Now there should be something nice to compare with, which yields to standard tests.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy root test should do the job.
$$C = \limsup_n \left( \left \vert (n+1)\left(\frac{(1+\sin(nπ/6))}{3}\right)^n \right \vert \right)^{1/n} = \dfrac23 < 1$$